# Assigning a Windows environment variable to a batch variable?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, environment-variables

I can't seem to assign an environment variable to another one inside a batch script.

For example, this will work:

```
set varA=C:\this\is\a\directory
```

and I can happily use

```
find /I "MyString" %varA%
```

without incident. However, if I try to assign it this way,

```
varA=%ENVVAR%\more\dirs
```

the batch just sticks in the CMD window until I stop it.

I'm still in the process of learning Windows' <s>obnoxious</s> unique scripting, so I can only speculate that it is throwing a fit over assigning a variable to another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you need to be careful of with setting variables in batch is not to use spaces unnecessarily. (I don't see this in your question, but wanted to call it out since I caught myself doing it while troubleshooting your issue.) For example:

```
set x=123
```

is not the same as

```
set x = 123
```

The former will set `%x%` to `123`, while the latter will set `%x %` to `123`. (Note the space after `x` in the variable name, and another one before `123` in the definition.)

Another thing to be aware of is you can't just say `var=value`. To set an environment variable, you *must* use the `SET` command.

So the proper syntax to set an environment variable that contains a path, and then one that expands upon that path, is as follows:

```
set x=C:\This\is\a\directory
set y=%x%\more\dirs
```

You can then use the `SET` command to verify the contents of these variables.

[image]

If you're just learning scripting languages in Windows though, it would probably be more useful for you to skip batch and jump straight into PowerShell. PowerShell comes standard with Windows Vista and above, and is also available for XP. Here's how the same job would be done in PowerShell.

```
$x='C:\This\is\a\directory'
$y="$x\more dirs"
```

(Note: There's a reason double-quotes were used when setting `$y`, while single-quotes were used for `$x`. In this case, we could have used either for setting `$x` but double-quotes were mandatory for setting `$y` since we needed to expand a variable. You'll learn more about that as you pick up the language.)

Then, to verify the variables, you can just call them directly.

[image]

PowerShell is also a lot less sensitive to spacing in most cases.

```
$x=123
```

is the same as

```
$x = 123
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer it, but it turns out I was specifying a wrong (non-existent) directory entirely. I use %APPDATA% so frequently that I forgot it points to Roaming rather than the actual folder.

Comment: @SacredCrumb Ah, then this becomes something of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Next time, instead of giving a general case for what you *think* is broken, provide the real details of what you're *actually* trying to do.